# Why am I getting 'call to a member function prepare() on null' when loading pdo?

Tags: php

I'm getting this error ('Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null') when passing a pdo instance into a class method. The error is thrown by the selectAll method. Stack trace is #0. I can't work out why I'm getting this error.

```
class QueryBuilder {


protected $pdo; 

protected $newTask;

public function __construct($pdo) {

  $this->pdo = $pdo; 
}

//Selects from table and returns to view

public function selectAll($table, $intoClass) {

  $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("select * from {$table} limit 1, 9"); 
  $stmt->execute(); 
  return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $intoClass); 

}

//Adds a new task to the table

public function addToTable($table, $newTask) {

    $done = 0; 

          try {
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("insert into {$table} (description, completed) values (:todo, :done)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':todo', $newTask);
    $stmt->bindParam(':done', $done); 
    $stmt->execute(); 
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
       die($e->getMessage()); 
    }

}

}
```

This is the index.php file, where I've saved the pdo variable.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

require "Task.php"; 
require "config.php"; 
require "connection.php"; 
require "QueryBuilder.php"; 

$pdo = Connection::make(); 

$query = new QueryBuilder($pdo); 

$tasks = $query->selectAll('todos', 'Task'); 

$newTask = $_POST['todo']; 

require 'user.view.php';
```

Connection.php is where I initialize pdo.

```
 class Connection { 

  public static function make() {

     try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=mytodo', 'root', ' 
', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
 } catch (PDOException $e) {
     die ($e->getMessage()); 
 }

    }

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection you're creating is the return value of the static function you're calling:

```
$pdo = Connection::make();
```

But that function doesn't return anything, making that connection object `null`:

```
public static function make() {
    try {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=mytodo', 'root', ' ', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die ($e->getMessage()); 
    }
}
```

Return the connection object from the function:

```
public static function make() {
    try {
        return new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=mytodo', 'root', ' ', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die ($e->getMessage()); 
    }
}
```